# How to add file extension inside of url with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

This url:

```
url = rtmp://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp3:audios/lesson/2/cancion?Expires=1386332537&Signature=mysignature__&Key-Pair-Id=my-key-par-id
```

I would like to add the extension `mp3` to all file name.

In this case the file name is `cancion`

The id of lesson is a dynamic value.

I would like to get this url something like:

```
url = rtmp://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp3:audios/lesson/2/cancion.mp3?Expires=1386332537&Signature=mysignature__&Key-Pair-Id=my-key-par-id
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simple `gsub` since this is URL and you can expect one occurrence of `?` so simple do.

`url.gsub!('?', '.mp3?')`

Usually I would go regex here but no need from previously stated reason.

Answer (score 4):

You can parse the URI, edit the path, then return the value

```
require 'uri/http'

u = URI.parse('rtmp://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp3:audios/lesson/2/cancion?Expires=1386332537&Signature=mysignature__&Key-Pair-Id=my-key-par-id')
u.path += ".mp3"
puts u.to_s
```

or use a simple regexp replace

```
u = 'rtmp://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp3:audios/lesson/2/cancion?Expires=1386332537&Signature=mysignature__&Key-Pair-Id=my-key-par-id'
u.gsub('?', '.mp3?')
```

The second approach can be used only if you can assume the format of the input is always the same.